# Smooth zoom in safari

Tags: safari

You know the way you smoothly zoom-in in mobile safari? How do I do that on my Mac + magic trackpad in regular safari?

Answer (score 3):

Its a pinch motion just like mobile safari.  To activate it, make sure Pinch Open and Close is ticked in System Preferences

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I did have pinch enabled and the "zoom thing" worked but it was not smooth. It works in very rough steps - 100%, 120% 140% or so.... instead I would like it to zoom smoothly from 100% trough 101%, 102%  all the way down

Comment: Actually, what I want is my desktop safari to zoom like preview....

Comment: Unfortunately, the zoom in and zoom out functions are hard coded to jump in largeish increments. The pinch options just trigger an increment after they detect your much finer pinches over a period of time.

Answer (score -1):

Wait for 10.7 "Lion" there'll you get the same zooming as on the iPad and you can even double-click on columns to zoom the to full window width.

Comment: How do you know that?